# python <=> c++ cross-language hash

Tags: c++, python, hash

I am writing a python program to look up a file. The file was created by a C++ program with a hash as filename ( `std::hash<std::string> hash_fn` ).
I know the string from which the hash was created, but I can't find a python hash function that produces the same hash (I tried `hash()` and all in `hashlib`).
As an example, the string

```
file:///home/ubuntu/Untitled.skp
```

should give the hash:

```
3133433022
```

Unfortunately I don't have control over the C++ program, only about the python script (or eventual python extensions).
Is it possible to find or implement the same hash function that C++ uses? Or should I try another approach?

Comment: The exact hash algorithm isn't specified by the C++ standard, AFAIR. So we need more information about your environment - or the hash value of the empty string might be all info we need.

Comment: check this out : http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm

Comment: The hash you show is really simple, any two strings starting with the same 5 letters will have the same hash.

Comment: @ch3ka: It's using glib/gstdio.h on Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dani Which hash are you referring to.  I don't see where the OP showed any hash.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The sample result he showed. you can easily understand the algorithm from it.

Comment: @Dani I can't (but the numeric results he shows doesn't correspond to what I get with `std::hash<std::string>` in g++ 4.4.2---although he claims it comes from the system hash function in g++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, internal hash functions like `std::hash` in C++ or
the Python hash function are not designed for external use.  When you're
designing such systems, strictly specify the hash function used, and
implement it in both systems.

If it's too late for this, and you've already used `std::hash`, then
about all you can do is find the sources for it (which depending on the
compiler, may not be available), back engineer them to find the hashing
algorithm used, specify it as your hash, and reimplement it in whatever
languages needed.  (You need to implement it in your own code, because
it could potentially change in the next release of your compiler.)

Comment: Thanks, as I said it is the standard hash and I assume the compiler is GCC. I don't know what hash fucntion the compiler uses, the source of the program is here:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/unity-shared/ThumbnailGenerator.cpp

Comment: @FreddiSchiller The problem is that the standard doesn't specify the actual hash function used, and doesn't even require the implementation to document it.  There's no guarantee that it won't change from one version of the compiler to the next.  (FWIW: some older versions of g++ used `h[i] = 31 * h[i-1] + c[i]` as their hash function; this is likely still the case.  Note that IIRC, they don't explicitly convert `c[i]` to `unsigned char`, so the results will differ depending on whether plain `char` is signed, and depending on the size of `size_t`.)

Comment: I might also add that implementing any C++ algorithm which depends on the behavior of unsigned integers is going to be a pain in Python.  You'll probably have to use long integers, and mask with 0xFFFFFFFF after each operation.

Answer (score 2):

To be compatible, use a known hash on both sides, like SHA-1. Python has it builtin, and if c++ doesn't have it built in, there are many libraries that do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the C++ part, you can make sure you use the same hashing algorithm on both sides. Alternatively, you can always have a look at the implementation of the `hash_fn` and try to re-implement the same functionality in Python.

Otherwise it may be quite hard to try to match the hashing functionality.